# XPath / PHP - Return index of specific tag that matches a regex

Tags: php, html, regex, xpath

I'm trying to get the index of a tag which href matches certain regex, but whatever I try is throwing me a warning that says that the expression is invalid. Here's an example.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$url_check = testurl.com
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);

$finder->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$finder->registerPhpFunctions('preg_match');

//Updated to fix some errors, still invalid expression
$index = $finder->evaluate("count((/ol[@id='rso']/li[not(@id) and @class = 'g' and h3[@class='r']/a[php:function('preg_match','/^(http://|https://|ftp://)?(www(\d+)?.)?($url_check)\/?$/', string(@href) > 0)]])/preceding-sibling::*)");
```

`$html` is a string that stores the html of a webpage, which contains something like this

```
<ol id="wrap">
  <li class="list">
    <h3 class="j">
      <a href="http://xxxxxx.com">Not the one I'm trying to match</a>    
    </h3>
  </li>
  .
  .
  .
  <li class="list">
    <h3 class="j">
      <a href="http://testurl.com">Click here</a>    
    </h3>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, and if you know a better/faster way to do this feel free to share :)

Answer (score 0):

I found at least three problems in your expression :

- `preceding-siblings` should be singular, not plural
- the `count()` function has no ending parenthesis
- `$url_check = testurl.com` has no quotes (should trigger a syntax error).

fixed code :

```
$index = $finder->evaluate("count(/ol[@id='wrap']/li[@class = 'list']/h3[@class='j']/a[php:function('preg_match','/^(http://|https://|ftp://)?(www(\d+)?.)?($url_check)\/?$/', string(@href) > 0)]/preceding-sibling::li[@class='list'])");
```

Moreover, the example html code you give us doesn't provide any result for the expression (each `<a>` element has no siblings whatsoever). So, even with these fixes, the expression still returns 0 for your test case, which is normal

Comment: The $url_check quotes are in my actual code, it's a sample. What I'm trying to achieve is counting the preceding siblings of the li that contains an a tag with attribute href that satisfies the . This is the first time I work with XPath so I'm having a hard time dealing with the syntax